# Firmware interface changed itself after disk replacement, laptop dead

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd, firmware

Specs:
Asus X556 8GB RAM with CD ROM 2 USB slots Nvidia GeForce 940M Intel core i5

I replaced Seagate Barracuda 1TB HDD which was preinstalled with a new WD NandBlue 3D 500GB SSD.

First boot with that SSD:
I booted into BIOS, it was completely different which is pretty strange because it shouldn't. I have installed Linux, no problem. That I used my laptop for about an hour, than I have powered it off. Than I tried to power it on and... nothing. **Completely dead**. Please help. Dead means that no led lights, no fan works, nothing. Tried removing battery over night. Nothing.

Comment: Have you tried going back to the HDD, or booting from USB with *no* internal drive?

Comment: Tried both, didn't work :( seems like motherboard is dead probably. But I've tried using multimeter and there is some voltage everywhere (about 20V I think).